# Replace on-success function while ajax is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have a function that makes an ajax call to the server. The code can pass two kinds of success and error functions. So, what I want to do is if the second request is sent without 1st being finished, re-assign success and error functions without sending a new request and use the current one. I am tracking ajax calls in `XHR.recordAudio`. Below code doesn't work, because it doesn't re-assign success/error functions to a newly passed functions. Any ideas?

```
recordAudio: function( args ){
    if( XHR.recordAudio.length > 0 ){
        //if the first call is not finished, 
        //replace the success and error functions

        XHR.recordAudio[0].success = function(data){
            XHR.recordAudio.pop();
            console.log( XHR.recordAudio );
            console.log("Success");
            args.success(data);
        };
        XHR.recordAudio[0].error = function(jqXHR){
            XHR.recordAudio.pop();
            console.log( XHR.recordAudio );
            console.log("Error");
            args.error(jqXHR);
        };
        //stop executing this function any further.
        return true;
    }
    
    var xhr = $.ajax({
          url: '/audio/record',
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'text',
          data: args.data,
          success: function(data){
              XHR.recordAudio.pop();
              console.log( XHR.recordAudio );
              args.success(data);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR){
              XHR.recordAudio.pop();
              console.log( XHR.recordAudio );
              args.error(jqXHR);
          }
    });
    XHR.recordAudio.push(xhr);
   }
```

Comment: do you want to override the current success handler, or provide another and have them both execute. I suggest looking into Deferred objects, as it is going to be far easier to manage and read than using the xhr (the xhr is actually a deferred object). http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: @KevinB: can you give example of both? In this particular example, it should be overridden.

Comment: Well, as far as I know you can't override a callback of a deferred object, you can only add more callbacks to it, which can be done with the `.done()` method on your `xhr` object.

Comment: Like this: xhr.done( args.success ); ?

Comment: Yes, just like in the api for ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: @KevinB: I'm guessing this will be fired on success, right? what about on error? (sorry for being pain in the neck :)

Comment: `.done` will fire on success, and `.fail` will fire on error. `.always` will always fire regardless of success and error.

Comment: great! That's all I wanted to know. Thanks a lot!